# app crashes because of the launchOptions being nil at the launch

Tags: ios, swift

This is my code in swift 2.2 , and i have written in

```
didfinishLaunchingWithOptions
```

as

```
if let locationValue : AnyObject? = launchOptions![UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey] as? [NSObject : AnyObject] {
    if (locationValue != nil) {
        let app : UIApplication = UIApplication.sharedApplication()
        var bgTask : UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid
        bgTask = app.beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler({ () -> Void in
            app.endBackgroundTask(bgTask)
        })
        self.startLocationUpdates()
        }}
```

error (EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION) occurs on this line

```
 if let locationValue : AnyObject? = launchOptions![UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey] as? [NSObject : AnyObject] {
```

Can anyone help me with how to handle the nil case here ? I tried if ..let statement as well .. thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anywhere you're using an exclamation mark for optionals is a place your app can potentially crash.  For the most part, you can generally fix it be replacing the exclamation mark with question marks.

The signature of `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is this:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool
```

The relevant argument here is `launchOptions`, whose type is `[NSObject: AnyObject]?`, an optional dictionary.  Before we can call methods on it (including trying to access elements via the subscript operator) we must unwrap it.

In your case, the most simple solution is:

```
if let locationValue = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey] {
    // use the location value
}
```

Per [the official Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Launch_Options_Keys):

> - `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey`
>
> The presence of this key indicates that the app was launched in
>   response to an incoming location event. The value of this key is an
>   NSNumber object containing a Boolean value. You should use the
>   presence of this key as a signal to create a CLLocationManager object
>   and start location services again. Location data is delivered only to
>   the location manager delegate and not using this key.

In the above code snippet, `locationValue` will be of type `AnyObject` (non-optional) due to the type of the dictionary.  But per the documentation, we know that it will be an `NSNumber` representing a `Bool` (which in Swift can be freely bridged to the useful type).

And we probably just care about the case when the value is true, right?

As such, we can rewrite the code snippet to the following:

```
if let locationValue = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey] as? Bool where locationValue {
    // the app was launched in response to a location event
    // do your location stuff
}
```

Although, strictly speaking, per the documentation:

> The presence of this key indicates that the app was launched in response to an incoming location event.

Between this wording and the fact that the actual value is just a true/false value, I'd almost wager that the fact that the key exists alone is enough information to assume the value is `true`.  If the app isn't launched for location events, the key probably simply doesn't exist.  And if it is, the value is probably always `true`.

And if you want to bet on this assumption, you can simply use the `_` for the variable name since we won't be using it:

```
if let _ = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey] {
    // etc...
}
```

Comment: Good explanation. Also you can do `if launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey] != nil`